# Sending Firebase message to topic to same user on multiple devices

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have an app that lets users authenticate with phone auth, and subscribe to topics to get notifications. If a user authenticates on two devices like an ipad and iphone, and subscribes to the same topic on both, when I send a message to that topic, it's only received on one of the devices. Is this correct and by design? If the user has an iPhone in their pocket and an iPad at home, the notifications may only get displayed on the iPad at home, and they miss the notification.

Comment: Recommend you recheck your test results.  Each device that has an instance of your app installed, and has subscribed to the topic, will receive the notification.  Whether a given user is signed-in on one device, both, or none, does not affect delivery of the notification.  I just verified this behavior on Android.  I strongly doubt it would be different for iOS devices

Comment: Interesting, OK I'll do some more testing to see if I can figure out the behavior I'm seeing. This was my assumption, but I didn't have another explanation for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. When you create a topic and lets say a user subscribe to  that topic, then that device will be associated with that topic.

If the user opens his account in another device and you send a notification, it won't be received on that device. So, **it will only be received on the device the user subscribed to that topic**. If the user is subscribed to a topic on multiple devices, all devices will receive the notification.

Also, if only one user is subscribed to that topic and he unsubscribe then it is no longer a topic.

Comment: OK thank you, I will test this and mark this the answer if it proves correct. I store a list of subscriptions in local storage, so it should be easy to go through and re-sub them on the active device on startup.

Comment: @regretoverflow yes, what I mean in the answer if person A subscribed to a topic called `Weather` in an ipad then he will recieve notification in that Ipad. If then he subscribed to the same topic on an iphone he should recieve notification there also.

Comment: does this mean he'll now receive it on both, or just the iPhone?

Comment: @regretoverflow yes should receive on both devices

Comment: Given that there is a limited amount of topics (2000) that any app can create, what is the best way to send notifications to a single user, but multiple devices? For example, I want to send invitation to a given users on his iPhone and iPad when he receives a friend request.

Comment: Replying to my comment above. This article explains it:
https://www.sentinelstand.com/article/device-group-management-with-firebase-cloud-messaging